# How to check if an interface/object property has a value using ngif angular 2

Tags: angular

So in my angular page, I only want to show certain sections if my interface/object has a property value. I had been using 
***ngIf='case?.docEvidence.length > 0'.**. Which works except for the objects that do not have a property value for that certain property. In which case I get there error

"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

My interfaces properties are as follows.

```
export interface ICase 
{
id: number; 
name: string;
description: string; 
fileType: string; 
suspects?: Array<ISuspect>;
offences?: Array<IOffence>; 
incidents?: Array<IIncident>;
policeofficers?: Array<IPolice>;
involved?: Array<IInvolved>;
casedeit?: Array<ICasedeit>;
docEvidence?: Array<IDocEvidence>;
witness?: Array<IWitness>;
victims?: Array<IVictim>; 
evidence?: Array<IEvidence>;
```

}

Preferably I would have the method be changed to ngIf there is a value that exists on that property as opposed to checking the length of of that array which in some cases may not be defined.

I am unsure of how to write the exact code for this problem. All help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you try using `*ngIf='case?.docEvidence?.length > 0'`

Comment: @trichetriche Yes same error sadly

Comment: Then do `*ngIf='case && case.docEvidence && case.docEvidence.length > 0'`

Comment: @trichetriche Thank you so much! Quite a simple fix but I started to get frustrated at these bugs! As you can imagine your mind doesn't think as logically as it usually does!

Comment: I totally get you. You can't imagine all the time I spent on rookie mistakes ... But once you know them, you learn how to fix them quick !

Comment: I am curious why doesn't `a?.b?.length` work. It should be the same thing as the proposed solution with `&&`.